# Get simple field value with post id

Tags: posts, plugin-simple-fields

I can retrieve the `simple field value` by following function.

```
simple_fields_value("simple_field_slug")
```

But is it possible to get value by using a post id ?

Comment: please let me know what is wrong with question before down-vote

Comment: Sorry, but this is not core functionality. Support for third party plugins are off topic, please refer to the developers documentation and if it is unclear, feel free to contact their support. Thank you :-)

Comment: Delete it yourself :-). Flagging your own questions reflects negative on your account, the system will punish you for excessive flags.

Comment: it doesn't allow me to delete as it has an answer

Comment: O yes, that is because you have an upvoted answer. It will simply be closed then as off topic, it will not get deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function second parameter is the "$post_id". Ref. http://simple-fields.com/documentation/api/getting-values/simple_fields_value/

```
simple_fields_value("simple_field_slug", $post_id)
```